# Running Powershell script from batch - Send-MailMessage not functioning

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sendmail

I am facing unusual issue with Powershell script.  I have written script to run DB queries which runs one STORED Procedure.  Below is the complete script:

```
$server="DBServer,Inst" 
$Database = "DATABASE" 
$ConnectionTimeout = 30 
$QueryTimeout = 120 
$Query="STORED_PROCEDURE" 
Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking 
$ds=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -Database $Database -ServerInstance $server -ConnectionTimeout $ConnectionTimeout -QueryTimeout $QueryTimeout
$date=(Get-Date).ToString() 
$ret=$ds.Return
```

--Query returns 0 or 1, 0 means SP Passed otherwise failed.

```
$From="abc@xyz.com" 
$SendCC= "aabbcc.b@xyz.com" 
If ($ret -eq '0') 
{ 
$Body=" STORED_PROCEDURE: <FONT COLOR=#00FF00> <b>PASS </b> </FONT> in <b> $server</b>:<i>$Database</i>; TimeStamp: $date" 
$msg="Test: STORED_PROCEDURE - SUCCESS " 
Write-Host "Sending Mail Notification - Ret 0"| 
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $SendCC -Subject $msg ($Body |Out-String) -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer mail.xyz.com
Write-Host "Notification Sent!!" 
}
```

This script works absolutely fine from my computer which is in xyz domain. I have created batch file to run this script as:

```
@pushd "D:\Temp\SM_SP"
powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\SP_SM.ps1 -noconsole
@popd
```

Even this batch file works fine in my computer, sends mail.. Works as expected! But the real issue is running the same in one of the test server (win Ser 2008 R2). Where the batch file when executed manually returns no errors – however I am not getting any mail notification.

*Note-
•   I have mentioned proper smtp server details in script, as I said the same script and batch are working fine in my computer which is in the same domain as this server.
•   I have tested Powershell inbuilt command “Send-MailMessage” in the server as:*

```
Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject Test -SmtpServer mail.xyz.com
```

*Where $from and $to both are my address and am receiving the mail absolutely fine.  But in the server when I execute the above script in Powershell console or through wrapped Batch file – am not receiving mail.*

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Regards
-Raaj

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the batch file is not related to the problem, since you say you get the same problem executing the PS script directly from the Powershell console.  To boil the problem down to its essentials, you could remove the batch code completely from your question and title etc.  You could also remove the stored procedure code, as that has nothing to do with the inability to send email.  I know so far I haven't helped answer your question, but a shorter more focused question will invite more answers.  :-)

Comment: Nope, I think I understood wrong.  On re-reading, here's what I think you're saying:  *On the server*, from a powershell console you can `Send-MailMessage -From "you@yourdomain.com" -To "you@yourdomain.com" -Subject Test -StmpServer mail.xyz.com` and it **does** work.  But if you put that exact same command in a script (.ps1) and run the script, it does not work.  Yet on your own computer it works whether run directly or through a script.  Is *that* correct?

Comment: Yes.. in server, from powershell console Send-MailMessage is working, but not when save and execute from .ps1

Comment: And when it does not work, you don't get any error message?  It appears to run fine but you just never receive the email?

Comment: I have come across this kind of behavior when the execution policy was defined by a group policy. You can check the applied group polices with `rsop.msc`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue several times as a result of Receive Connector settings in Exchange. We typically will just add the IP of a server to allow it to relay if we are going to start using it for sending email, otherwise we want connections refused.

If you're using exchange go to Server Configuration->Hub Transport and check what you have listed under "Receive mail from remote servers that have these IP addresses" on the Network tab. If you're using some other mail server I'd refer to the documentation on connection permissions for it. Also, if you're using a different user account on the server than you are using on your desktop you may want to try a Run as different user and see if it's something with the permissions of the account you're using on the server.